# Java Multiple Array Recursion regardless of array size

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have three arrays:

```
{}    
{a, b, c}
{d, e}
```

I am trying to combine them to get the following arrays:

```
{a, d}
{a, e}
{b, d}
{b, e}
{c, d} 
{c, e}
```

The problem I am coming across is the first empty array causes a nested for loop to not run at all - logically makes sense. ie:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < bL.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dL.size(); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < oL.size(); k++) {
```

What I am trying to find is the most efficient way to combine the three arrays regardless of their size.  Most of the time all three have elements, but there are cases where one might generate an empty set.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:  Adding output for all three arrays**

Input - 
    {a,b}
    {c,d}
    {e,f}

Output - 
    {a,c,e}
    {a,c,f}
    {a,d,e}
    {a,d,f}
    {b,c,e}
    {b,c,f}

**EDIT: It's only possible for the first or third array to result in an empty set**

Comment: Why don't you just recursively call a method that combines two arrays and inside that method you'd handle the special case of empty arrays? You'd not even have to call it recursively, just call it for the first two arrays and then for the current combination result and the next array.

Comment: Suppose the first array had elements {f,g}. What should the answer be in that case?

Comment: @GregS I assume he wants a cartesian product, although it differs in the fact that empty arrays/sets are effectively ignored.

Comment: @Thomas I can see how the method would work. Would that be considered common practice to achieve the cartesian product?

Comment: @Josh Producing Cartesian products of potentially unlimited sets explicitly isn't too common because of the danger of consuming loads of memory. Usually, you also want to filter your result based on some criteria, and the two operations are rolled into one. But if memory consumption isn't a problem and you can't reduce the size of the result straight away, then go ahead.

Comment: Well, I can't tell you whether that's the common practice or not, but it seems reasonable. However, you're not calculating the cartesian product if one of those sets was empty, in that case the result should actually be an empty set.

Comment: @biziclop The sets are limited in size. Memory is an issue.  Faster is always better as well.  There is a lot of optimization prior to forming these arrays so that each result is unique.  I will optimize further once I get the correct results. Unfortunately recursion seems necessary - unless there is another way to combine arrays in java, fingers crossed.

Comment: @Thomas The cartesian product is not the result I am looking for then.  That is a new term to me.  I am looking for the combination of the arrays.  I don't know if there is a more technical term. Here to learn though :D

Comment: @Josh: are you specifically trying to avoid recursion? It's possible to do it using loops, but recursion is so much more elegant.

Comment: @tom not trying to avoid recursion.  But the for loops that I posted in the OP will not work because if any one of the arrays is empty, none of the loops will run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are going through arrays of `int` values, here is what you can do:

```
void printCombination(int[][] data, List<int> partial) {
    if (partial.size() == data.Length) {
        for (int i : partial) {
            if (i != -1) {
                System.out.writeln(" " + i);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    if (data[partial.size()].length == 0) {
        partial.add(-1);
        printCombination(data, partial);
        partial.remove(partial.size()-1);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i != data[partial.size()].length; i++) {
        partial.add(data[partial.size()][i]);
        printCombination(data, partial);
        partial.remove(partial.size()-1);
    }
}
```

Initial call looks like this:

```
List<int> partial = new ArrayList();
int[][] data = new int[][] {new int[] {}, new int[] {1,2}, new int[] {3, 4, 5}};
printCombination(data, partial);
```

Comment: Where does 'p' and 'str' come from? Trying to follow the logic.  I'm actually using Character[].

Comment: There seem to be some errors in your code: 1. Why do you check the length of the list against the length of the 2D array? I assume you want that condition to be `partial.size() == data[p].Length`, don't you? 2. I assume you're missing the outer loop over `data`. You use the variable `p` but don't declare it.

Comment: @Josh Oops, I lifted the code from another answer I gave earlier today, and forgot to rename variables. I edited the code to fix these.

Comment: @Thomas I edited the code. The first check is actually right: I'm checking the length of `partial` against the outer dimension of the list. When they are equal, `partial` is actually "complete". The outer loop over `data` is the recursive invocation itself, so it is not needed.

Comment: Wouldn't the line `partial.add(data[partial.size()][i]);` produce ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception when trying to access the empty array?

Comment: Also, it looks like the logic creates a single list with all the elements from each of the arrays rather than multiple arrays that hold all the possible combinations of single elements from each array.

Comment: @Josh No, there would be no exception, but the code would not run as expected, because the loop would run zero times. You would need to modify it slightly to support empty arrays (see my edit).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Wouldn't the ouput still be `{1,2,3,4,5}` and not `{1,3}{1,4}{1,5}{2,3}{2,4}{2,5}`?

Comment: @Josh Once you understand the way the solution works, you should have no trouble making it format the output the way you need (hint: it's two additional lines of code in the first `if` block).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7593/discussion-between-josh-and-dasblinkenlight)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple recursive approach, which returns the result as a 2D ArrayList instead of printing it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[][] x = { {}, {"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e"} };
        System.out.println(cartProd(x));
    }

    public static ArrayList< ArrayList<String> > cartProd(String[][] x)
    {
        return cartProd(x, new ArrayList<String>(), 0);
    }

    public static ArrayList< ArrayList<String> > cartProd(String[][] x, ArrayList<String> current, int index)
    {
        ArrayList< ArrayList<String> > result = new ArrayList< ArrayList<String> >();

        while (index < x.length && x[index].length == 0)
        {
            index++;
        }

        if (index == x.length)
        {
            result.add(new ArrayList<String>(current));
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x[index].length; i++)
            {
                current.add(x[index][i]);
                result.addAll(cartProd(x, current, index + 1));
                current.remove(current.size() - 1);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```